# LUIS not able to fetch proper entity

Tags: azure-language-understanding

In sentence like -

> Can you finish it by 30th April 2019

Entity needs to be extracted is **DeadLine - 30th April 2019**

But there can be sentences like

> Refer to the report I sent to you 22nd April 2019 and prepare the
>   chart by 29th April 2019.

Entity needs to be extracted is **DeadLine - 29th April 2019**

but LUIS is fetching multiple dates and not the deadline as 22nd April 2019. How can I train LUIS in these scenarios to fetch proper entity? I mean fetch entity as per the context?

Comment: What type of entity are you using to define your date(s)? You should use the prebuilt datetimeV2 entity, if you are not, as it's already configured to handle different words and syntax.

Comment: Using prebuilt entities. Here the problem is, if there are multiple entities, LUIS cant understand the context of deadline.

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding how you are constructing your entities. Are you wrapping 'DeadLine' into datetimeV2? Can you screenshot and post how your entities as well as used?